# When i post a form the submit a form i get cannot call method "submit " of null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

When i post a form the submit a form i get cannot call method "submit" of null
but i dont know why it wont post. I set the idstatus with jquery. But the variable wont be posted somehow.

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>/agenda.php/index/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="id" id="idstatus" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();" value="See more" />
</form>
```

Comment: There is no need to have a onclick handler on submit button, unless you are doing something on click instead of just submitting.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Google chrome Browser

Comment: Change the button type to type "button". Use jQuery to attach an event (.submit) to your form and use the callback function to handle your request. But still we're missing some info. Where to does is load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>/agenda.php/index/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="id" id="idstatus" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <input type="submit" value="See more" />
</form>
```

Comment: To get proper code formatting, you need to indent blocks. I've edited it for you. You may also want to consider adding a sentence or two explaining the OP's mistake. Just posting code is not always helpful in explaining to the OP what they were doing wrong. That said, welcome to SO and thanks for contributing

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Enter some text in the fields below, then press the "Submit form" button to submit the form.</p>

<form id="myForm" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>/agenda.php/index/" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit form">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Make a seperate function , it will work.

Comment: Still this code didnt fix the problem. I get the same error.